# Flush all messages from a Qpid Proton Connection instead of waiting?

Tags: c++, qpid

Proton supports a feature called "bundling" which uses bandwidth more efficiently by sending multiple proton messages at the same time. I would like to flush all current messages instead of waiting. How do I do this?

This is using the 0.17 Version of the C++ API.

Comment: Please be a bit more detailed in your question, it's hard to guess at what you are doing.  When you say proton which language and which client?  What have you tried, what isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the C API exposes a method "Advance()" for the Link object, which seems to perform what I am looking for. However, this is not available currently in the C++ API. There are varying levels of support for Proton features across the different languages at this time.

Additionally, bundling can be disabled altogether during Proton configuration if you so desire.